# Access property of a generic type inside lambda expression

Tags: c#, mongodb, generics, lambda

The title may be ambiguous, but let me explain.

I am working with MongoDb and with the c# driver for MongoDb, we can create a `FilterDefinition<T>` to create a filter to fetch data as follows :

```
var Filter = Builders<TestClass>.Filter.Eq(x => x.AnyProperty, Value);
```

I am trying to put this code inside a reusable generic method, so that i don't end up writing the same code again and again. I won't be including the entire function here, but inside the function, i am trying to do something as follows :

```
var Filter = Builders<T>.FIlter.Eq(x => x.AnyProperty, value);
```

Now the drawbacks are :

- `T` is a generic type, meaning it doesn't have the property i am looking for. So, i try to get the type of `T` and get the property that i am looking for by name, as follows :

  `...FIlter.Eq(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName), value)`

This results in an exception :

> Unable to determine the serialization information for x => x.GetType().GetProperty("UserName"). // UserName is the property name

So, my question is, what can i do here for the generic type, which would be equivalent of `x => x.PropertyName` inside the lambda expression ?

**Update**

Forgot to mention, i did try this :

```
var Filter = Builders<T>.FIlter.Eq("PropertName", value);
```

But it doesn't return the results from the database, where as this does :

```
var Filter = Builders<MyClass>.FIlter.Eq("PropertName", value);
```

I really wonder why!

**Update 2**

Definition of `Filter.Eq` is as follows :

```
 public FilterDefinition<TDocument> Eq<TField>(FieldDefinition<TDocument, TField> field, TField value);
```

Comment: Where does this error originates from ? Is it the Mongo driver or your code, since if its your code then its possible fix and would be much more complex is the Mongo driver causes it

Comment: Also what's the definition of the `Filter.Eq`, what kind of object it expects, I assume, its an object type, which can take any property

Comment: Yes, you're right. By the way, i am not entirely sure what throws the exception as the code doesn't break and i only get the exception inside my browser. However, my browser points me to this class `MongoDB.Driver.ExpressionFieldDefinition<TDocument, TField>.Render(IBsonSerializer<TDocument> documentSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry, bool allowScalarValueForArrayField)`

Comment: I'm assuming this doesn't work because the driver tried to convert it to some query other than C#. Using `GetType` there will of course not work. That's the same with EntityFramework. If you have .net logic in a query it can't convert it to SQL (or whatever) so you get an error. It's just an assumption but it'd make sense to me. And `x => x.Bla` works because x would represent a table and Bla a column so it can easily translate that to whatever is used for the query.

Comment: Try `x => x.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(x)`, since its expecting the value for comparison not just the `PropertyInfo`

Comment: I tried that, same error occurs.

Comment: Answer my second comment what's the definition of the `FIlter.Eq`, looks like its expecting ExpressionTree, that's why its breaking and you need to supply `MemberExpression` instead for access at the runtime

Comment: @MrinalKamboj, this is what the `Eq` function looks like `Eq<TField>(Expression<Func<TDocument, TField>> field, TField value);`

Comment: Off the top of my head, the Mongo driver uses reflection to obtain the property name from a MemberExpression. `x => x.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName)` is not a MemberExpression, so this can't work. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: And instead of `Filter.Eq(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName), value)`, you could simply do `Filter.Eq("UserName", value)`. So why do you want to do this using generics and reflection?

Comment: @CodeCaster, and that's exactly what i tried. But what ends up happening is, `Builders<T>.Filters.Eq(PropertyName, Value` is not the same as `Builders<MyClass>.Filters.Eq(PropertyName,Value)`. The reason i am saying this is because using `T` doesn't return the value from the db, but using the class instead of `T` does!.. That's why i am puzzled... Check my update.

Answer (score 3):

> **In the code**

`FIlter.Eq(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName), value)`, my undersatnding is that Mongo driver is expecting an `Expression`, which is automatically created when you use the Metadata like in original case `x => x.AnyProperty`

> In this case you need to explicitly supply `MemberExpression`as follows

```
var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T),"x");

var memberAccessExpression = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameterExpression, typeof(T).GetProperty("AnyProperty"));
```

Now you can supply to the `FIlter.Eq` value `memberAccessExpression`, in this case it will fail at run-time, if the  `AnyProperty` is not part of `type T`, since its verified at the run-time.

In `ExpressionTrees`, this is the replacement of the `x => x.AnyProperty`

> **Edit 1:**

Reviewing the Mongo DB Driver documents, following are the important details on the [Definitions and Builders](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/reference/driver/definitions/), there's an example as follows:

```
var builder = Builders<Widget>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Eq(widget => widget.X, 10) & builder.Lt(widget => widget.Y, 20);
```

Following is the definition of the [FilterDefinitionBuilder.Eq](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinitionBuilder_1.htm), which expose the `Eq` and various other filters:

```
public FilterDefinition<TDocument> Eq<TField>(Expression<Func<TDocument, TField>> field,TField value)
```

In this case, we need a generic type `TDocument`, which is the main class and `TField`, which is the type of the field on which filter is applied, therefore code in your case would be:

```
var builder = Builders<T>.Filter;

// Use makeMemberAccessExpression created above
var filter = builder.Eq(Expression.Lambda<Func<T,string>>(makeMemberAccessExpression), "<stringValue>");
```

> **Important points:**

1. As it can be seen in the Mongo documentation, we have 2 generic types, `TDocument` and `TField`, here you are working with just one, so with the above code it will be restricted to string as type for `TField`, until and unless you make that also generic, which is your choice, otherwise all your fields shall be of specific type that you supply, which is string in this case
2. More important is the value shall be of type `TField` that you supply else it will not work and will fail at compile time
3. There's another overload, `Eq<TField>(FieldDefinition<TDocument, TField>, TField)`, which would work in a similar way, but since it expects `FieldDefinition<TDocument, TField>`, we need to supply the `Expression<Func<TDocument,TField>>` as part of the class, both overloads translates into similar code

Comment: `Eq` accepts a `FilterDefinion` as the first parameter, so i can't pass `memberAccessExpression `.

Comment: Ca you paste the schema in the Question update, my guess is somewhere it needs `MemberExpression`, in fact you were supplying Lambda in your actual code

Comment: Is `FilterDefinition<T>` your custom class

Comment: Now you need to post the definition of `FieldDefinition<TDocument, TField>`, please reduce it to the point where it has .Net code, not their custom code

Comment: I need to find another way.... digging in too deep will make it more complicated.

Comment: My guess is you are instead supplying `ExpressionFieldDefinition<TDocument, TField>`, https://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_ExpressionFieldDefinition_2.htm,
Its derived from `FieldDefinition<TDocument, TField>` and it has `Expression` property where you can supply `MemberExpression` is my code

Comment: No it would not that's ideal and clear way just create and supply `ExpressionFieldDefinition<TDocument, TField>`, check some examples and it would accept your generic code

Comment: Let me check and find the way to create it

Comment: Check the Updated version, it has **Edit 1**, which explains how to handle your specific case using the generic code